# Bind a parameter within the select statement of crosstab

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I have a statement that creates a pivot table with the crosstab function. My goal is to have the user input a list of values, i.e. customer ids and for the query to return a pivot table with the values for each customer and month. I create a token for each entered customer_id and want to bind each token to the corresponding value.

The resulting query looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab (
  $$SELECT customer_id, month, value FROM tcustomers WHERE customer_id IN (:id_0, :id_1, :id_2)
  GROUP BY month, customer_id
  ORDER 1,2$$, $$SELECT UNNEST('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}'::text[])$$
) AS ct("Customer" text, "1" text, "2" text, "3" text, "4" text, "5" text, "6" text, "7" text, "8" text, "9" text, "10" text, "11" text, "12" text)
```

The result is something along these lines:

```
          |1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12
customer_1|0|0|0|0|100|0|1|...
customer_2|1|0|2|200|0|0|1|...
customer_3|1|0|2|200|0|0|1|...
....
```

In this example the user entered three customer ids (customer_1, customer_2, customer_3) bound to the three tokens. Upon executing I get the error Message: 'ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $1'

I tried replacing the $$ quoting with single quotes and escaping the single quotes within the statement with double quotes ('') but then I get a syntax error at the position where my tokens are.

I can get it to work without binding by simply putting the input values directly into the statement but I'd really prefer to use binding.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code:

```
$$SELECT customer_id, month, value
FROM tcustomers
WHERE customer_id IN (:id_0, :id_1, :id_2)
GROUP BY month, customer_id
ORDER 1,2$$
```

is just a regular string insofar as the `crosstab()` function is concerned. Rather than do the binding at the level of the SQL statement, you could define a string and then `sprintf()` the parameter values in and pass that to the SQL statement:

```
$sql = sprintf('SELECT customer_id, month, value ' .
               'FROM tcustomers ' .
               'WHERE customer_id IN (%s, %s, %s) ' .
               'GROUP BY month, customer_id ' .
               'ORDER 1,2', $id_0, $id_1, $id_2);

$result = pg_query_params($dbconn,
  'SELECT * FROM crosstab ($1, ' .
      '$$SELECT unnest(\'{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}\'::text[])$$ ' .
  ') AS ct("Customer" text, "1" text, "2" text, "3" text, "4" text, "5" text, "6" text, "7" text, "8" text, "9" text, "10" text, "11" text, "12" text);',
  array($sql));
```

Comment: That's what suspected. I already have system in place where I can handle user input, guess I'll have to modfiy the existing input procedure to directly use what the user inputs in certain cases.